# C#: Insert into SQLite database content gone

Tags: c#, sql, xml, sqlite

I just started using sqlite in c#, it's all easy and good but then I realized that the saved data will be gone after the application is reset.

So I tried to find a way to store my data in some kind of file.

XML came in handy, because there's also a function already for write/read xml to/from the database.

All of this is working great with no problems.

I start the application and all my data that I stored into the database, the last time, is still there!

Now I try to append some new data into the database, it works but now all the data that was stored before in my database is gone except the new line...

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        datenbankDataSet.ReadXml(@"C:\Users\ekehr\Desktop\newXML.xml");

        datenbankDataSet.AcceptChanges();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: Diese Codezeile lädt Daten in die Tabelle "datenbankDataSet.Table". Sie können sie bei Bedarf verschieben oder entfernen.
        this.tableTableAdapter.Fill(this.datenbankDataSet.Table);
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(global::SQL_ENTRY.Properties.Settings.Default.DatenbankConnectionString);
        try
        {
            string sql = "INSERT INTO [Table] (Id, name) VALUES("+textBox1.Text+", '"+textBox2.Text+"')";
            Console.WriteLine(sql);
            SqlCommand exeSQL = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
            cn.Open();
            exeSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
            this.tableTableAdapter.Fill(this.datenbankDataSet.Table);
            cn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("NEUER EINTRAG!","INFO");
            datenbankDataSet.AcceptChanges();
            datenbankDataSet.WriteXml(@"C:\Users\ekehr\Desktop\newXML.xml");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm desperate by now, please help me! :(

Comment: Remove the fills, you just want to insert.

Comment: if i remove the fills, there will be no changes at all...
the data i stored is still there but im not able to insert anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean all your data will be gone ?!

Sqlite is simply a file database. It acts like a SQL DB, but instead of running a SQL service etc, it just stores the data locally in a file (usually with `.sqlite` extension, but it doesn't really matter), which you can then move around.

Also, it's free. We like free.

Having said that, if you're just mocking around with data and want to save it, you can always write/append it to a file. For example:

```
var path = @"C:\test.txt";  // Where to save to

// Lets assume this is your input
var lines = new string[] {"one line", "two line", "three line", "party"};

// This will simply write them all to the file
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(path, lines);

// This will append them  to the file
System.IO.File.AppendAllLines(path, lines);

// And then you can read it back
var loaded_from_file = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines
```

---

As per comment, I'm still not sure on why you're filling a sqlite db with XML data, but any how, download [sqliteadimn](http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/). It's a DB viewer for sqlite and it will let you easily open your sqlite file, see what's inside, and play with your data. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thx for the nice info about the file-extension!:)
But my problem isnt solved that way i think, because i save the data from the database to an external file, a xml-file...
isnt that the same, because i populate the database via a xmlread-method...
So the population of the database is no prob, but the insert is because all existing data seams to disappear... :(

Comment: OMG i was looking over the whole i-net for something like that!!!
Thank you very much, i think this will help!

Comment: :) Sometimes a little help can go a long way. Glad I could have helped.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you insert the id every time you query the database, may be this is the problem. this could replace the old data that has the same id.

Comment: I thought the same way, but i watched out to not use the same id twice.
But an interesting behaviour is, that if i try to use the same id for an insert that is already in the database when it is populated from a xml-file, its no problem because all data is gone from the table before the insert happens...
but if i try to insert an id that i freshly inserted he gives me an exception...
Its strange i think the problem should be somewhere above the insert.